# For accessibility, how to properly set the link role and link action to a TextView?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have this TextView that holds a link to a website. I want to manually handle the clicks on the textView to then open the link using a special web router with special cookies and other properties. (tl. dr. I want to manually handle links inside a TextView). Note that I will still be opening a third-party Browser after my processing.

My question is, for TalkBack user, how do you properly set the `link` role to the TextView and also make the Links option to show in the context menu as if it were a natural link?

So far I have added the `link` role at the end of the contentDescription, but I don't know how to add the option for `Links` in the accessibility context menu of the View. See following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a context menu during Talkback showing the options for Links]